# Search a particular string, split it and to store it

Tags: java, string

I have a string: `155Kč/kg\x0D\x0A\x0D\x0AVP15 1554,1555,1556,`

I want to store it as `VP15 1554, VP15 1555, VP15 1556` in Java.

Here is my code so far:

```
String order = VP15 1554, VP15 1555, VP15 1556;
if(order.contains("VP15"+" "+order.matches("\\d.*\\d")+",") && order.matches("\\d.*\\d")) {             
    String parts[]=order.split(",");
    System.out.print("parts divided are"+parts[0]);
}
```

The problem is that I am not able to store it.

Could someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String order = "...";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*VP15");
Matcher m = p.matcher(order);
if (m.find()) {
 String suffixes = order.substring(m.end() + 1);
 int index = 0;
 String[] suffixesArray = suffixes.split(",");
 for (String suffix : suffixesArray) {
   System.out.print("VP15 " + suffix + (index++ < suffixesArray.length - 1 ? ", " : ""));
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
*.VP15
^ It throws this error and m.endIndex() seems undefined for type Matcher

Comment: sorry, the dot goes before the asterisk - edited the code, hope it works now